# Rails 7 engine how to make uncompiled stylesheets available to host app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, rails-engines

So I have a file not found problem.
I have an engine that works in development mode in the engines test/dummy app, the engine allows the editing of sass variables and stores them in a theme table, the variables are used by a sass partial such as _banner.scss containing variables used in the main stylesheet such as $banner_color which is then imported into the main stylesheet which in turn is precompiled using an initializer in the engine.rb file and inclusion in the app/config/engine_name_manifest.js.

The files are all available in development with the local dummy app but not in the eventual host app due to the assets being compiled.

I have a rake task that takes the data, updates the relevant partial e.g. _banner.scss with the data from the theme table but of course the partials are not not available in a host app as the engine has already compiled them.
I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to edit the raw, uncompiled stylesheets then recompile them. Obviously my Capistrano deploy script will need to reapply the stylesheet changes every deployment but that is just a rake task call.
What approach should I take? Should I find a way to copy the css files to the host app in an engine initializer? Should I use a different approach entirely, I have started looking at propshaft but that is a massive step to replace sass rails and I'm not sure how that would help

The engine

```
require "deface"
require 'ccs_cms_admin_dashboard'
require 'ccs_cms_custom_page'
require 'ccs_cms_core'
require 'css_menu'
#require 'tinymce-rails'
require 'delayed_job_active_record'
require 'daemons'
require 'sprockets/railtie'
require 'sassc-rails'

module CcsCms
  module PublicTheme
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace CcsCms::PublicTheme
      paths["app/views"] << "app/views/ccs_cms/public_theme"

      initializer "ccs_cms.assets.precompile" do |app|
        app.config.assets.precompile += %w( public_theme_manifest.js )
      end

      initializer :append_migrations do |app|
        unless app.root.to_s.match?(root.to_s)
          config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded.each do |p|
            app.config.paths['db/migrate'] << p
          end
        end
      end

      initializer :active_job_setup do |app|
        app.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
      end

      config.to_prepare do
        Dir.glob(Engine.root.join("app", "decorators", "**", "*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
          Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
        end
      end

      config.generators do |g|
        g.test_framework :rspec,
          fixtures: false,
          request: false,
          view_specs: false,
          helper_specs: false,
          controller_specs: false,
          routing_specs: false
        g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot
        g.factory_bot dir: 'spec/factories'
      end

    end
  end
end
```

The Css class that writes the css

```
 class Css

  def get_stylesheet_path
    Rails.root.join("app/assets/stylesheets/ccs_cms/public_theme")
  end

  def write_css(theme)
    update_css_files_for(theme.banner, '_public_banner.scss', BANNER_ARRAY, BANNER_FIELD_MAP)
    update_css_files_for(theme.banner.font, '_public_banner_font.scss', BANNER_FONT_ARRAY, BANNER_FONT_FIELD_MAP)
  end

  private

    def update_css_files_for(model_record_to_use, css_file, array_to_use, field_map)
      amended_css = amend_css_for(model_record_to_use, css_file, array_to_use, field_map)
      create_css_files_for(css_file, amended_css)
    end

    def amend_css_for(model_record_to_use, file_name, array_to_use, field_map)
      original_css_array = IO.readlines("#{get_stylesheet_path}/#{file_name}")
      new_array = []
      original_css_array.each do |line|
        new_line = line
        array_to_use.each do |ma|
          if line.start_with?(ma)
            field_name = field_map[ma.to_sym]
            new_line = ma + ": #{model_record_to_use[field_name.to_sym]};"
            #puts("@@@@ original line: #{line}, ma: #{ma}, Field name: #{field_name}, value: #{theme[field_name]}")
            break
          end
        end
        new_array << new_line
      end
      new_array
    end

    # ---- File and I/O Handling ---- #

    def create_css_files_for(file_name, css_array)
      File.open("#{get_stylesheet_path}/#{file_name}", "w") do |file|
        file.puts css_array
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: can you clarify why you're editing engines css in your main app? engine css files can be required/imported in the main app css. just declare sass variables first then import engine sass files. if main app css is changed, everything is recompiled; precompilation should also just work since everything is required in main app. did i misunderstand what you're trying to do? and what file exactly is not found?

Comment: @Alex I am not editing the css files in the host app, the engine, when in the host app is unable to find the css files

Comment: @Alex It is not desirable for anything other than either include the engine or do not include the engine, there should be no effort at all made on the host app. The engine, one of many, should be, and is, completely self contained and totally responsible for all functionality it provides., None of the css files are found that I wish to edit as they are precompiled as per engine.rb settings shown in my post. So I need to find a way to make them available.

Comment: @Alex specifically, as mentioned the partial _banner.scss can not be found but there will be others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying. If I understood correctly here my take on it.

> partials are not not available in a host app as the engine has already compiled them

Partials are still there, precompilation just outputs `*.{css/js}` files into `public/assets/` that are declared in `app/assets/config/manifest.js`.

To get to engines files, instead of `Rails.root` use:

```
CcsCms::PublicTheme::Engine.root
```

In `Css` class, for example:

```
def get_stylesheet_path
 CcsCms::PublicTheme::Engine.root.join("app/assets/stylesheets/ccs_cms/public_theme")
end
```

To support changing theme engines. Theme root can be set in an engine initializer to something like `Rails.configuration.theme_root` and used in the main app.

Because your theme is also configurable, I think it's better to read theme's original sass files but not modify them, copy them into a tmp folder and update with values from theme table, then output a `theme.css` in the main app with sass.
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass

```
​# Compiles all Sass
$ sass tmp/theme/application.scss:app/stylesheets/theme.css
```

Then let Rails take over the precompilation process.

Another option is to have one sass configuration file and only update this file. That way there is no dependency on the file structure of any particular theme.

```
import 'configuration' // sass variables with values from theme table
import 'banner'        // uses sass variables only
...
```

Also just use css variables, if that's an option, and avoid all of the above complexity; no precompilation, no redeploys when theme table changes.

**Update** for css variables.

Just so we're on the same page. I meant these css variables:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties. If Internet Explorer is not a priority for you, this is the best solution.
The setup is something like this:

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.erb -->
<!-- NOTE: with turbo this loads only once; full page refresh is needed when @theme changes -->
<head>
  <style>
   :root { --text-color: <%= @theme.text_color %>; }
  </style>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
</head>
```

```
/* app/assets/stylesheets/application.css */
p { color: var(--text-color); }
```

Possible fix to avoid amending css files. Use `erb` interpolation inside the sass files. No need to amend every time a theme configuration is changed. In development compiles on the fly. In production it has to be precompiled again when theme configuration is changed; no amending.

```scss
// _banner.scss.erb
p { color: <%= Theme.text_color %>; }
```

You could even use `amend_css_for` function to insert literal erb code and save some time. For example

```
new_line = ma + ": <%= Theme.#{model_name}.#{field_name} %>;"
```

Finally, if you don't want to touch engine files and because these files are not part of the main/host app (as in literally two separate folders in the filesystem). You have to make a copy when amending; read from `CcsCms::PublicTheme::Engine.root` write to `Rails.root`.

```
def get_stylesheet_path
  CcsCms::PublicTheme::Engine.root.join("app/assets/stylesheets/ccs_cms/public_theme")
end

# but save to main app

def create_css_files_for(file_name, css_array)
  File.open("#{Rails.root.join("app/assets/stylesheets/ccs_cms/public_theme")}/#{file_name}", "w") do |file|
    file.puts css_array
  end
end
```

Comment: Firstly a massive thank you for your help, I need to digest this information and may come back with more questions but up voted in the meantime.

Comment: you say "Also just use css variables, if that's an option, and avoid all of the above complexity; no precompilation, no redeploys when theme table changes." this is exactly what I am doing literally just updating the sass variables, does this mean that css does not need to be recompiled once the sass variables have been updated? the files I am updating only contain variables. and OMG, Just used your code to check the files existence and it worked, I'm going to leave this question for a day or two before accepting an answer because your answer deserves a bonus but I can't add a bonus yet.

Comment: Ok, duly digested, given that the theme is updated during runtime,  the engine provides theme editing functionality to the admin panel in the host app, when the theme is saved and the sass variables are updated using the path you gave me updates the actual files in the engine itself rather than the css that the host app is using, that CcsCms::PublicTheme::Engine.root took me to the actual file system on my dev machine that contained the actual engine which is not what I need, I need to update the css in the host app, if you have any further ideas I would dearly love to hear them

Comment: updated. hope one of the solutions will be useful.

Comment: OK, 24 hours on and I find that the problem is that I need the engines stylesheets to exist in the host application folder structure, and the best solution for me is for the engine to have an appropriate initializer in the engine that will copy them to some location for me, preferably into an assets stylesheets sub folder unless there is an automatic way to achieve this? could you give me a clue as to what initializer I could use to copy the stylesheets? I could use a rake task to copy or code the intializer but I'm just not sure when the best point to do the copying would be

Comment: OK, Just realised what an idiot I've been, forget that last comment, I assume in a production server the Engine.root will point to the installed gem path. I can work with this from here. Thank you again